# preventing sub class methods to run from base class constructor

Tags: c#, inheritance

The question title seems a little bit odd doesn't it. Anyway. So I have one base class which has some private fields, protected properties and a single constructor that takes one argument and I have several sub classes of that base class. whenever any of those subclass methods are called the sub classes are required to be instantiated and after the method is done executed the object is destroyed so if the method will be called again new instance of the class should be made. (Its a WCF service) Now, the thing I want to do is the following. whenever the certain sub class constructor is called I call the base class constructor explicitly with some certain parameter (different for every sub class, Note: no sub class methods are the same), When the base class constructor is called I want to check something according to that argument and if it passes the check then I want to allow the execution of sub class method. In any other case I want it NOT to run the sub class method. So I want something like this. when the method is called the sub class has to be constructed and for that, base class has to be constructed as well and if the check fails in the base class' constructor I want to prevent that method from running. I can just have a bool property and  set it in base class' constructor and check it on every method call. but I want to make something more general. May be the way that I'm suggesting Is not right either. So you understand what I want I guess. Any suggestion would be appriciated. thanks in advance

```
class BaseClass
{
    private bool _isValid;

    private SomeService someService;

    public BaseClass(SomeEnum value)
    {
        someService = new SomeService();

        if (someService.Validate(value))
        {
            _isValid = true;
        }
    }

    protected internal bool IsValid { get { return _isValid; } }
}

class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    // object declaration
    public SubClass () : base(SomeEnum.SomeValue)
    {
        // constructing some objects here
    }

    public Response Operation('parametereGoHere')
    {
        if (IsValid)
        {
            // perform operation. construct Response object and return it
        }
    }

    // other methods omitted.
}
```

So whenever the `Operation()` method is called `SubClass` has to be constructed which causes the `BaseClass` to be constructed and the base class sets the value of `_isValid` which is then use to check for validity, but I wanted to make something more general. lets that instead of just setting the value of `_isValid` to true just do nothing or set some other properties and if the `Valiate()` failed just stop the execution and don't to anything at all. In this case the calling routing wouldn't be able to call `Operation()` if we somehow managed to stop the construction of class. If it's not possible I'm perfectly happy with the solution I have right now. But if it is I will be glad to see that. Note: In every sub class, methods are different and I have to check `IsValid` to allow the execution of method.

Comment: A code sample would be easier to understand than your narrative.

Comment: Paragraphs would help, too.

Comment: All sounds very convoluted and even if it was possible to hack something together with constructors you have to ask if it's a good idea. Just factor all the construction logic out into a factory pattern and leave constructors / inheritance alone.

Comment: I will post the code sample shortly. I just don't have it with me right now

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `out` parameter to get the constructor to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Very hard to follow what you want, but it sounds like you want a case where the base constructor doesn't do anything sometimes. Then simply make a base constructor that doesn't do anything, and call it (with the `: base()` call).  Use a dummy argument if necessary.

```
class A {

   public A() { a= 1; }
   public A(double dummy); { }
}

class B 
   public B() : base() {  // calls the base constructor that does something
   }
   public B(int) : base(1.0) {// class the base construct that does nothing 
   }
}
```